# How to capitalize the start of a string and lowercase the other characters using pattern matching in list comprehensions?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, parse-error

I am trying to capitalize the first letter of a string to an uppercase letter and all the other letters to lowercase. This is my code so far:

```
capitalize :: String -> String

capitalize word = [ toUpper x | x <- word, head` word ]
```

I have tried a few variations of the guard behind, but they do not work. I want to use pattern matching to separate the string into the head and tail, but am unsure how to. Is there a way, using list comprehension, to do this?

Also, can we put multiple guards in one place? Because I am under the impression that `isAlpha` should be one of the guards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a list comprehension is a great tool for this particular function. You can do all sorts of mapping and filtering with that, but there's no easy way to treat the first element of the list differently from the others.

Personally, I think the cleanest way to write this function is with simply pattern matching:

```
capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize "" = ""
capitalize (x:xs) = toUpper x : map toLower xs
```

The `capitalize "" = ""` line isn't strictly necessary if you're sure you'll never try to use this on an empty string, but I prefer writing functions that can never give a runtime error, and it seems fair to say that capitalizing an empty string should give another empty string back.

The main work is done on the last line, which uses the `x:xs` pattern to separate the list (strings are just lists in Haskell) into the `x` the head (or first letter), and `xs` the rest of the string. Then we use `toUpper` to make the first letter uppercase, and `map toLower` to make the rest lowercase (`toLower` and `toUpper` work on characters, not strings, but a string is a list of characters so we use `map` to apply the function to each character in the string), and put them back together with the cons operator `:`.

Comment: yep I got it! Thanks for explaining it to me clearly :) But as I am learning about list comprehensions at the moment, I was wondering if there is a way to change the code above into a LC. 

Would changing the map toLower xs into a LC work? And how does one do the list comprehension here?

Comment: i tried my hand at it,, and this is what i have so far:

capitalise :: String -> String
capitalise "" = ""
capitalise (x:xs) = toUpper x : map[ toLower xs | xs <- ""]

when i try to load the code, it does not work. evidently i am not very good at this

Comment: It's easy to turn a `map` into a list comprehension - you're trying to overcomplicate. In this case you want `capitalise (x:xs) = toUpper x : [ toLower y | y <- xs]` (the variable name `y` could of course be replaced by anything)

Comment: Oh, so you have to add a new variable into the code. Alright, I got it! Thanks alot!

Comment: Think of list comprehensions and `map` as the same thing. `map f xs = [f x | x <- xs]`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann and even `fmap`, with MonadComprehensions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here is a solution with list comprehension:

```
capitalize word = [ if i==0 then toUpper x else toLower x
                  | (i,x) <- zip [0..] word ]
```

There's also a syntactic extension for sugaring the `zip`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

capitalize word = [ if i==0 then toUpper x else toLower x
                  | i <- [0..]
                  | x <- word ]
```

Instead of an explicit index running to infinity that requires an `if` condition, we can also use the character-modifiers directly in a list:

```
capitalize word = [ m x
                  | m <- toUpper : repeat toLower
                  | x <- word ]
```

This again could also be written without list comprehension but explicit zip instead:

```
capitalize = zipWith id $ toUpper : repeat toLower
```

Comment: `zipWith id . repeat` is `map`, but more -- it is an _explicitly sequential_ `map`! this is just beautiful. and `repeat` doesn't even allocate new space, I think. :)

Comment: @WillNess well, this is basically [the `ZipList` applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) right there!